# Spring or Struts web based tool to list content of database tables

Tags: database, hibernate, spring, struts

Is there an open source web based tool preferably based on Spring(or struts) and Hibernate that will list the contents of a database table? I can write one but there are hundreds of tables so im wondering if i can use an existing open source tool that will list the contents of the table based on what i select.

Basically all i want to do is specify the database connection details and the list of tables i want to be able to view and the tool to list the data based on a table that i select from a list (no need to re-invent the wheel). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with them but have a look at:

- [Java phpMyAdmin for All DB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaweb-basedph/)
- [Web-based SQuirreL SQL Client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/websquirrelsql/)

PS: It's weird, both projects actually have the same files.

Comment: i tried the first one. its quite good but it uses quite a lot of advanced tricks to be able to load data from a table. You have to write sql to list the table data and it limits the rows that are returned. I would like to be able to use an automated test tool to just click a link and display the data. Ps. They are both the same project and files are the same from both project. :) Thanks anyway